# Symfony REST API authentication without sfGuardPlugin

Tags: api, rest, symfony1, authorization

I'm trying to find information on securing a HTTP REST API in a Symfony project, but all I can find is information about using sfGuardPlugin. From what I can see, this plugin isn't very useful for web services. It tries to have user profile models (which aren't always that simple) and have "sign in" and "sign out" pages, which obviously are pointless for a stateless REST API. It does a lot more than I'll ever have need for and I what to keep it simple.

I want to know where to implement my own authorisation method (loosely based on Amazon S3's approach). I know how I want the authorisation method to actually work, I just don't know where I can put code in my Symfony app so that it runs before every request is processed, and lets approved requests continue but unsuccessful requests return a 403.

Any ideas? I can't imagine this is hard, I just don't know where to start looking.

Comment: How exactly do you want to authenticate? Are you going to send a key with each request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding what I was looking for by digging into the code for [sfHttpAuthPlugin](https://github.com/dator/sfHttpAuthPlugin). What I was looking for was a "Filter". Some details and an example is described in the [Askeet sample project](http://www.symfony-project.org/askeet/1_0/en/18).

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin for RESTful authentication -> http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfRestfulAuthenticationPlugin

Not used it though ....

How where you planning to authenticate users ?

The jobeet tutorial uses tokens ... http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/15

Answer (score 0):

Stick a HTTP basicAuth script in your <appname>_dev.php (Symfony 1.4 =<) between the project configuration "require" and the configuration instance creation.

Test it on your dev. If it works, put the code in your index.php (the live equivalent of <appname>_dev.php) and push it live.

Quick and dirty but it works. You may want to protect that username/password in the script though.

e.g.

```
    $realm = 'Restricted area';

        //user => password
        $users = array('username' => 'password');

        if (empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="'.$realm.
                   '",qop="auth",nonce="'.uniqid().'",opaque="'.md5($realm).'"');

            die('Text to send if user hits Cancel button');
        }

    // || !isset($users[$data['username']]

        // analyze the PHP_AUTH_DIGEST variable
        if (!($data = http_digest_parse($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) || !isset($users[$data['username']])) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="'.$realm.
                   '",qop="auth",nonce="'.uniqid().'",opaque="'.md5($realm).'"');
            die('Wrong Credentials!');
        }

        // generate the valid response
        $A1 = md5($data['username'] . ':' . $realm . ':' . $users[$data['username']]);
        $A2 = md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].':'.$data['uri']);
        $valid_response = md5($A1.':'.$data['nonce'].':'.$data['nc'].':'.$data['cnonce'].':'.$data['qop'].':'.$A2);

        if ($data['response'] != $valid_response) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="'.$realm.
                   '",qop="auth",nonce="'.uniqid().'",opaque="'.md5($realm).'"');
            die('Wrong Credentials!');
        }

// function to parse the http auth header
function http_digest_parse($txt)
{
    // protect against missing data
    $needed_parts = array('nonce'=>1, 'nc'=>1, 'cnonce'=>1, 'qop'=>1, 'username'=>1, 'uri'=>1, 'response'=>1);
    $data = array();
    $keys = implode('|', array_keys($needed_parts));

    preg_match_all('@(' . $keys . ')=(?:([\'"])([^\2]+?)\2|([^\s,]+))@', $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        $data[$m[1]] = $m[3] ? $m[3] : $m[4];
        unset($needed_parts[$m[1]]);
    }

    return $needed_parts ? false : $data;
}

// ****************************************************************************
// ok, valid username & password.. continue...
```